# How to change Youtube subtitles to srt subtitle file?

Tags: video, youtube, subtitles

I can get the subtitles of this video on Youtube from the transcript box. It is in the following form:

```
00:02
Künstliche Intelligenz ist auf dem Vormarsch.
00:05
Manche sprechen von einer neuen Evolution,
00:08
die das Leben auf unserem Planeten fundamental verändern könnte.
00:13
Künstliche Intelligenz betrifft jeden Lebensbereich.
```

How can I change this text to a srt file so that my kmplayer can read it?

Comment: Is downloading .srt file directly from YouTube an option?

Comment: @gronostaj Yes. Is that possible?

Comment: Actually you're missing information here. The transcript box only has information on when a subtitle is displayed, not when it stops being displayed. However, if you don't care, you could easily write a script to convert them.

Comment: @mtak you wouldn't want to obtain this information from the transcript box as you would then lose the length of time each caption should appear on screen. YouTube only shows the start times in the caption box for readability reasons but you can still download all of the SRT file information if you use a third-party site to extract it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YouTube only provides a video's owner with an option to download SRT files.

Fortunately, YouTube SRT files can always be extracted from the site using third-party sites, such as [DownSub.com](https://downsub.com/), which also provides options for all the Google Translate alternative languages that are available on the original video.

[image]